# Плавность отрисовки в WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть программа-тест. На ней панель размещена и она является задним фоном с разными фотографиями которые меняются по очереди. При обновлении фото на ней происходит не понятное мерцание.
Вот что я пробовал

```
private const int WS_EX_COMPOSITED = 0x02000000;

        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ExStyle |= WS_EX_COMPOSITED;
                return cp;
            }
        }
```

Но это никак не повлияло. Очень благодарен, если кто-то поможет!

```
{
 panel2.BackgroundImade = Properties.Resourses.MyRes1;
 panel2.Visible = false;
 panel1.Visible = true;
 panel1.BackgroundImade = Properties.Resourses.MyRes;
}

{
 panel2.Visible = true;
 panel1.Visible = false;
 panel1.BackgroundImade = Properties.Resourses.MyRes3;
```

Comment: А почему не используете PictureBox?

Comment: [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171018-00/?p=97245). Вы используете как-либо Graphics этой панели? `panel.CreateGraphics()` вызываете?

Comment: Нет, не использую.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас есть два способа решить проблему мерцания:

1. Рекомендуемый способ - использование атрибута [double buffering](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-reduce-graphics-flicker-with-double-buffering-for-forms-and-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Фактически, это означает установку `DoubleBuffered = true;` для панели или для всей формы - надо попробовать и так, и так

2. Если это не поможет - тогда есть "классический хак": у вас должно быть 2 панели. Одного размера и расположенные по одному и тому же Location. Одна видимая, вторая - невидимая. В невидимую загружается следующая фотка. Потом - меняем атрибуты видимости местами: делаем первую панель невидимой, вторую (в которую уже полностью загрузилась фотка) - видимой.

Comment: `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` и есть двойная буферизация.

Comment: @aepot - спасибо за замечание, я этого не знал

Comment: К сожалению, у панели нет такого свойства DoubleBuffered, а применив его к форме результата не даёт. Пользуясь "классическим лайфхаком" я столкнулся с тем, что у меня просто белый экран.

Comment: Хм... не видя кода, трудно сказать что то определенное. не может быть, что у Вас одновременно у обоих панелей Visible==false?

Comment: @S.H. Добавил код

Comment: Спасибо. Какая то загадка! надо попробовать....

Comment: Пробовали, что-то получилось?

Answer (score 0):

```
class panell : Panel
{
    protected override bool DoubleBuffered { get => true; }
}
```

Использовать panell вместо Panel.
Если не поможет то через рефлексию:

```
using System.Reflection;
Type type = panel.GetType();
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
propertyInfo.SetValue(panel, true, null);
```

Сделал в интерактиве, ничего не мерцает даже без двойной буферизации:

```
#r "System.Windows.Forms"
using System.Windows.Forms;
Form f = new Form();
f.Show();
string s1 = @"..\18--w--1280.jpg";
string s2 = @"..\20--w--1280.jpg";
using System.Drawing;
f.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(s1);
Timer t = new Timer();
t.Interval = 500;
int i = 0;
t.Tick += (s, a) => f.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(i%2==0?s1:s2);
t.Tick += (s, a) => { f.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(i % 2 == 0 ? s1 : s2); i++; };
t.Enabled = true;
Button b = new Button();
f.Controls.Add(b);
```

Можете поделиться своим исходником с мерцанием?

Comment: Вы используете lastView1, а у меня panel.

Comment: @ЯрославОвчар неудачная копипаста, исправил.

Comment: К сожалению, у панели нет свойства DoubleBuffered

Comment: `panell` - что за название такое? Дайте контролу говорящее имя. Скажем, `DoubleBufferedPanel`. Или `FastPanel`, так как предполагается быстрая отрисовка. В любом случае имя должно быть в [PascalCasing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces) и описательным.

Comment: Ответ не помогает.

Comment: Так даже нету чего скидывать, просто по кнопке меняется фотка на панельке, всё. Фото беру из сборки ресурсов. Прописую таким образом: panel.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resourses.MyPfoto. Всё.